How to add slide animation to this code (slider)
I want to add a small slide animation when changing from one slide to another.
Animation something like this simple move to next slide: Example
ChatGPT unfortunately did not help :D
Code Snippet


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.yxslide');
  const dotsContainer = document.querySelector('.yxdots-container');
  const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.yxprev');
  const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.yxnext');
  let slideIndex = 0;

  // Generowanie kropek dla każdego slajdu
  slides.forEach((_, index) => {
    const dot = document.createElement('span');
    dot.classList.add('yxdot');
    dot.addEventListener('click', () => {
      goToSlide(index);
    });
    dotsContainer.appendChild(dot);
  });

  const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.yxdot');

  // Funkcja przejścia do określonego slajdu
  function goToSlide(index) {
    if (index < 0) {
      slideIndex = slides.length - 1;
    } else if (index >= slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 0;
    } else {
      slideIndex = index;
    }

    slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
      if (index === slideIndex) {
        slide.classList.add('yxactive');
        dots[index].classList.add('yxactive');
      } else {
        slide.classList.remove('yxactive');
        dots[index].classList.remove('yxactive');
      }
    });
  }

  // Przejście do poprzedniego slajdu
  prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    goToSlide(slideIndex - 1);
  });

  // Przejście do następnego slajdu
  nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    goToSlide(slideIndex + 1);
  });

  // Uruchomienie automatycznego przejścia slajdów
  // Możesz odkomentować tę część, aby uruchomić automatyczne przejście slajdów
  /*
  setInterval(() => {
    goToSlide(slideIndex + 1);
  }, 5000);
  */

  // Wyświetlenie pierwszego slajdu po załadowaniu strony
  goToSlide(slideIndex);
});
.yxslider-container {
  position: relative;
}

.yxslides {
  display: flex;
}

.yxslide {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.yxslide.yxactive {
  display: block;
}

.yxarrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.yxprev {
  left: 0;
}

.yxnext {
  right: 0;
}

.yxprev,
.yxnext {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px;
}

.yxdots-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.yxdot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.yxdot.yxactive {
  background-color: #333;
}

.xslide {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #282828;
  color: #ffffff;
}
<div class="yxslider-container">
  <div class="yxslides">
    <div class="yxslide yxactive">
      <div class="xslide">Slide 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="yxslide">
      <div class="xslide">Slide 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="yxslide">
      <div class="xslide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Dodaj więcej slajdów według potrzeb -->
  </div>
  <div class="yxarrow yxprev">&#10094;</div>
  <div class="yxarrow yxnext">&#10095;</div>
  <div class="yxdots-container">
    <!-- Kropki będą tutaj generowane dynamicznie przez JavaScript -->
  </div>
</div>




Check out the Swiper slide library if js. https://swiperjs.com/

Yes, but I only want a fragment of the code, I don't want the entire library

Using the transition property of css should fix your problem.
Like in this snippet:
.slides {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  color: white;
}

See this example:


const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const slides = document.querySelector('.slides');
const slideWidth = slides.clientWidth;
let currentIndex = 0;

function goToSlide(index) {
  slides.style.transform = `translateX(-${index * slideWidth}px)`;
  currentIndex = index;
  updatePagination();
}

function nextSlide() {
  if (currentIndex === slides.children.length - 1) {
    goToSlide(0);
  } else {
    goToSlide(currentIndex + 1);
  }
}

function prevSlide() {
  if (currentIndex === 0) {
    goToSlide(slides.children.length - 1);
  } else {
    goToSlide(currentIndex - 1);
  }
}

function createPagination() {
  const pagination = document.querySelector('.pagination');
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.children.length; i++) {
    const dot = document.createElement('span');
    dot.classList.add('dot');
    dot.addEventListener('click', () => goToSlide(i));
    pagination.appendChild(dot);
  }
  updatePagination();
}

function updatePagination() {
  const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
  dots.forEach((dot, index) => {
    if (index === currentIndex) {
      dot.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      dot.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
}

createPagination();
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  color: white;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.slider-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slider-btn.left {
  left: 10px;
}

.slider-btn.right {
  right: 10px;
}

.pagination {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dot.active {
  background-color: #333;
}
<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide" style="background-color: #282828;">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="slide" style="background-color: #282828;">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="slide" style="background-color: #282828;">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <button class="slider-btn left" onclick="prevSlide()">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="slider-btn right" onclick="nextSlide()">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="pagination"></div>
</body>



